# GraphQL - How do I use the return value as a variable for the next query?

Tags: graphql

How do I take the return result from the first query and assign that result to a variable to use in the second query? I need the first value result before I can make the second call, but would like to make only 1 call to accomplish this. My query:

```
query {
    test1(sku: "12345"){                    
          price
    }
    test2(itemPrice: $price){ 
          isSuccessful
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Query:

```
query {
    test1(sku: "12345"){                    
          price
    }
    test2(itemPrice: $price){ 
          isSuccessful
    }
}
```

When a query is parsed, it’s converted to an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), or a tree. In your case your query will look like below:

[image]

Now there are 3 phases involved with every graphQl query :

1.**Parse** — A query is parsed into an abstract syntax tree (or AST). ASTs are incredibly powerful and behind tools like ESLint, babel, etc.

2.**Validate** — The *AST* is validated against the schema. Checks for correct query syntax and if the fields exist.

3.**Execute** — The runtime walks through the AST, starting from the root of the tree, invokes resolvers, collects up results, and emits JSON.

> The root Query type is the entry point to the tree and contains our
> two root fields, **test1** and **test2**. The `test1` and `test2` resolvers
> are executed in parallel (which is typical among all runtimes). The
> tree is executed breadth-first, meaning user must be resolved before
> its children `price` and `isSuccessful` are executed.

So basically in a single query you cannot solve your problem as of now.

Comment: Hi, do you know if there is some kind of workaround? rearrange the queries in some way?